# Statistics Probability problem (I need a strategy)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I can’t get my head around the correct way of beginning to solve this question:

> It is known that $25\%$ of 11-year-old children have no decayed, missing, or filled (DMF) teeth. In a sample of $10$ children, find the probability that exactly $3$
>
> (a) have DMF teeth.
>
> (b) do not have DMF teeth.

I know that $\Pr(DMF) = .75$ and $\Pr(DMF*)=.25$, but I am confused about the sample part. I don’t have a strategy to do it.

Answers are: $0.003$, $0.25$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is only one question, so can only be one answer not two. Do  you know the binomial distribution?

Comment: @Paul  One of the questions was accidentally deleted in a previous edit.  The statement of the problem has been corrected.

Comment: Look up the binomial distribution. It gives you the probability of r "successes" out of n, where the probability of each individual "success" is p and each individual "success" is assumed independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that each child is equally likely to have decayed, missing, or filled teeth, we can treat this as a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) problem with $\Pr(DMF) = 0.75$.

The binomial distribution states that the probability of obtaining exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials, each of which has probability $p$ of being successful, is 
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the number of ways exactly $k$ successes can occur in $n$ trials, $p^k$ is the probability of $k$ successes, and $(1 - p)^k$ is the probability of $n - k$ failures.

For the probability of exactly three children having DMF teeth, $p = 0.75$ and $k = 3$.

For the probability of exactly three children having no DMF teeth, $p = 1 - \Pr(DMF) = 1 - 0.75 = 0.25$ and $k = 3$.